# Fading in new paragraphs

Tags: jquery, dom

i'm working on some kind of twitter new ticker using jquery and i'm stuck on a visual effect. I have all the tweets i want to show formatted as strings stored into an array.
The strings are like this:

```
<p><a href="http://twitter.com/user">user</a>: tweet text</p>
```

I would like to have the paragraph added to the container DIV one at a time, with some kind of fade in effect, like the one you get in the example when you click on the button:
http://jsbin.com/uneso (example is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734041/how-to-add-paragraph-on-top-of-div-content/5001289#5001289)).

I've tried using the code from the example and i wrote this:

`for (i=0; i<tweetsArray.length; i++){

var tweetTmp = tweetsArray[i];
$(displayContainer).append(tweetTmp).fadeIn("slow");

}`

But it looks like all the appends get done together and then one single fadeIn() effect is applied to the whole div.

Any idea why it does behave like this?

Thanks in advance, 
Marcello

P.S. I've tried looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165387/jquery-fading-out-performing-an-action-then-fading-back-in) too but i still couldn't solve my problem.

Comment: http://www.twitterama.org if you want to see the final result! thanks to everybody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is looping through without waiting for the fades to occur. If you want to wait for each fade to occur before appending the next div, you'll need to either use the [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) completion callback (my preferred solution) or delay adding them (the favorite of some others I respect).

Here's are rough examples:

Using the completion callback:

```
var tweetArray = [
  "This is tweet 1",
  "This is tweet 2",
  "This is tweet 3",
  "This is tweet 4"
  ];

$("#btnGo").click(function() {
  appendAndFade(document.body, tweetArray);
});

function appendAndFade(parent, tweets) {
  var index;

  index = 0;
  doOne();

  function doOne() {
    if (index < tweets.length) {
      $("<p>")
        .html(tweets[index++])
        .hide()
        .appendTo(parent)
        .fadeIn(doOne);
    }
  }
}
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/osuxi4/2)

Note how we use the callback on `fadeIn` to trigger the next append-and-fade-in (`doOne`).

Using [`delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/):

```
var tweetArray = [
  "This is tweet 1",
  "This is tweet 2",
  "This is tweet 3",
  "This is tweet 4"
  ];

$("#btnGo").click(function() {
  appendAndFade(document.body, tweetArray);
});

function appendAndFade(parent, tweets) {
  var index;

  for (index = 0; index < tweets.length; ++index) {
      $("<p>")
        .html(tweets[index])
        .hide()
        .delay(index * 400)
        .appendTo(parent)
        .fadeIn(400);
  }
}
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/osuxi4/3)

Comment: thanks, it works perfectly. the callback function is a much more clear and elegant approach. problem was i didn't know the fadeIn() function works asynchronously.

Comment: @Marcello: Ah, yes, that *would* be a problem. :-) Glad that helped.

Answer (score 0):

The [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) method behaves asynchronously: it queues the animation and immediately returns to the caller. You can use its last argument to provide a callback function that will be called when the effect completes.

So, with a little refactoring, you can do something like:

```
function fadeTweet(tweets, index, displayContainer)
{
    if (index >= tweets.length) {
        return;
    }

    $("<p>" + tweets[i] + "</p>").appendTo(displayContainer).fadeIn("slow",
        function() {
            fadeTweet(tweets, index + 1, displayContainer);
        });
}

fadeTweet(tweetsArray, 0, $(displayContainer));
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that the fadeIn() method works asynchronously, you've been really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Rbm7Q/ - example working code.

Some code to see can be found below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var elk = new Array('<p><a href="http://twitter.com/user">user</a>: tweet text 1</p>', '<p><a href="http://twitter.com/user">user</a>: tweet text 2</p>');

function appEl(_id) {
    if (elk[_id] != undefined) {
        $('#testHolder').append(elk[_id]);
        $('#testHolder p:eq(' + _id + ')').hide().fadeIn("slow", function(){
            _id = _id + 1;
            if (elk[_id] != undefined) {
                appEl(_id);
            };
        });
    }
}
appEl(0);
});
```

Comment: thanks! i went for T.J. approach just because it looked simpler, but i'll definitely look into yours to understand the callback function better!

Comment: Sure! Good luck with your project :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the fadeIn() should be applied to the appened paragraph.

```
$.each(tweetsArray, function(i, tweet){
    $(displayContainer).append( $(tweet).css('display', 'none').fadeIn() );
});
```

I'm not sure you're array is compatible with "$(tweet)",
if not try to wrap the tweet in a <p> like

```
$('&lt;p&gt;', {'html': tweet}).css('display', 'none').fadeIn();
```

Comment: Love the very concise approach. unfortunately the array isn't compatible as you predicted :( adding the code to each tweet is a little unpractical. Thanks!